# Attempting to add a column heading to the newly created csv file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, export-to-csv

I'm trying to add the add the header to my csv file that I created in the code given below:
[image: This is the code im using]

There's only 1 column in the csv file that I'm trying to create,
the data frame consists of an array, the array is
[0.6999346, 0.6599296, 0.69770324, 0.71822715, 0.68585426, 0.6738229, 0.70231324, 0.693281, 0.7101939, 0.69629824]
i just want to create a csv file with header like this

**Desired csv File** , I want my csv file in this format

[image]

Please help me with detailed code, I'm new to coding.

**I tried this**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(c)
df.columns = ['Confidence values']
pd.DataFrame(c).to_csv('/Users/sunny/Desktop/objectdet/final.csv',header= True , index= True)
```

[image: Im getting this]

But i'm getting this csv file

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Please provide code in formatted text so others can help to debug. Also just to confirm, you want those numbers in your header?? Or is it add a column with those array of values?? If it's the later, your title is misleading, it should be how to add a column. I think a simple grid or screenshot of the desired csv file is required.

Comment: i made the changes and added the desired csv file image

Comment: do you mean add clomuns in existing csv ?

Comment: No, I'm creating the csv file, when I create it I'm getting like in the last image above, I want to get a heading on top of the float values (the heading should be confidence values)

Comment: use this  df.to_csv('final.csv' , float_ format=True, columns=True, header=True, index=True)

Comment: It says TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable when i add columns =True

Comment: your action pd.DataFrame(c) is creating a new dataframe with no header, while your df is a dataframe with header.
You are writing the dataframe with no header to a csv, that's why you dont get your header in your csv. You need to change your last line to df.to_csv(...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
import pandas as pd
array = [0.6999346, 0.6599296, 0.69770324, 0.71822715, 0.68585426, 0.6738229, 0.70231324, 0.693281, 0.7101939, 0.69629824]
df = pd.DataFrame(array)
df.columns = ['Confidence values']
df.to_csv('final.csv', index=True, header=True)
```

Your action pd.DataFrame(c) is creating a new dataframe with no header, while your df is a dataframe with header.

You are writing the dataframe with no header to a csv, that's why you dont get your header in your csv. All you need to do is replace `pd.DataFrame(c)` with `df`

Comment: It didnt work, theres is a column but with the heading 0 , i want it as confidence values

Comment: from your edit of the question, seems like you are using
   pd.DataFrame(c).to_csv('/Users/sunny/Desktop/objectdet/final.csv',header= True , index= True)

please change it to df.to_csv(...) to see if it works

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.